# How do I set a Calendar Object in VB.NET so that it has no date selected?

Tags: vb.net, calendar

By default, the Calendar object in a VB.NET form will have 'todays date' selected.

How do I set it so that by default, it does not have a date selected whatsoever, until the user performs a click action?

Thanks,
C.

Comment: This seems to go against the purpose of the Control. Also against the basic configuration of the underlying type (DateTime), which does not have Nothing/null by default (a date/time has always to be selected). Also I don't see the exact point of attempting to do that: seeing the today date selected (or any other one) should be OK. What you might do is "hiding the fact" that is selected by (temporary) modifying the style of the selected day; for example: setting by default a selected-date style which does not highlight (e.g., same one than non selected) and modifying it to the one you want...

Comment: ... after the first selection is performed.

Comment: @varocarbas: there are hundreds of valid reasons for not having a date in a date control. For example, in record about a person's life, the date of death probably shouldn't be defaulted to today or any other date. Likewise, the date of receipt of a shipment should be empty when the shipment record is initially created (and until the shipment actually arrives).

Comment: @user7378: Is this for win forms or asp.net?

Comment: Solved the problem by using a workaround avoiding it entirely. Thank-you anyway folks.

Comment: @competent_tech I am not saying that there are no reasons for not letting a date field blank (there are tons). But most of calendars/date-pickers (if not all of them) in programs/webs have always a date selected; this was the point of my complain: being the most normal situation. PS: it is ASP.NET.

Comment: @varocarbas: I agree that many calendar controls default to today's date, but I have set to see one that does not support clearing the date in some manner, usually by setting DateTime.MinValue, specifically for the reasons that I have stated.

Comment: @competent_tech as commented in your answer: MinValue and today are basically the same. The OP didn't want any date to be selected (what I found a bit uncoventional).

Comment: @varocarbas: I think that you need to do some research on DateTime values. MinValue = 01/01/0001 12:00:00 AM. Today is quite a bit later than that.

Comment: @competent_tech well... this is starting to be a bit... I don't know. OK. I have just shared my opinion, don't see the point of continuing this discussion. MinValue is the minimum value you allow to the control (I always set this value to the one I want) and I thought that you meant that (not the default one, equivalent to null). When I said that it is equivalent to Today, I meant because a date has to be selected (no matter if it is 07-01-2014 or 01-02-1990) and this was what the OP intended to avoid.

Answer (score 1):

The usual method for clearing the date in a date control is to either set the value of the control to DateTime.MinValue.

Some third party controls store the value in an object and let you set the value to DBNull.Value or Nothing to indicate that no selection has been made.

Comment: Sorry to correct you. But your first statement is equivalent to the today option (just having something selected). Regarding your second proposal; I am not sure that you should recommend to rely on external libraries, just to allow null dates (you might change the selected-date style as suggested; I complained but also helped :)).

Comment: @varocarbas: I have been creating commercial ASP.Net and WinForms applications for 10 years. DateTime.MinValue is not and never has been equal to DateTime.Today. Every calendar control that I have used has used DateTime.MinValue as an empty string. And it is quite frankly ridiculous to suggest that external libraries should never be used to resolve a particular problem that you are having. If the customer wants or needs a date control that shows an empty date when you set it to null, then that is what you provide, you don't tell them they have to change the date in every form.

Comment: As said above, I don't see the point of continuing this discussion. But I want to clarify that I don't have any problem with external libraries, when there is no easy, in-built option. And here I thought that it was one, but well... we clearly think pretty differently.